# Cannot load pages using custom scheme, CDVURLSchemeHandler not called

Tags: cordova, cordovawebview

I have native app with an embedded Cordova Web view, and the app loads fine over the default `file` scheme. But when setting the scheme and hostname config preferences, the web view points to about:blank.

```
<preference name="scheme" value="app" />
<preference name="hostname" value="localhost" />
```

What we know...

1. Cordova (6.2.0) detects that the scheme is not file, and loads the `CDVURLSchemeHandler` plugin. Its initializer is called.
2. `CDVWebViewEngine.loadRequest` tries to load `app://localhost/index.html`, and web view's scheme handler is set (`[((WKWebView*)_engineWebView).configuration urlSchemeHandlerForURLScheme:@"app"]` return non-null). Yet `startURLSchemeTask` method is never called. Why not???
3. Just to be sure, I added the custom scheme to Info.plist:

   ```
    <key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
            <array>
                <string>app</string>
            </array>
            <key>CFBundleURLName</key>
            <string>com.myapp</string>
        </dict>
    </array>
   ```

What did I miss?